# Aligning DIVs using float property

Tags: html, css

How would I align divs like the following (example content below the divs)...I set float to left for both div1 and div2 but then div3 floated to the top right, how do I prevent this?

```
<div1>                <div2>
What is the temp.?    ____________________
Is it raining?        ____________________

<!-- Contains main content -->
<div3>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set a clear fix to place after the floated divs.  This is what I do.

Make this class in your stylesheet:

```
.clear {clear:both}
```

The after your two floated divs, right before `<div3>` include this html:

```
<div class="clear"></div>
```

This should keep your 3rd div below the floated divs.